# How to install ruby 1.8.7 back on Ubuntu 14.04 after upgrade?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, ruby

Upgrading to 14.04 removed my ruby 1.8.7. I need it back. :) Badly. Some old projects still rely on it.

Gems seems to be left untouched.

How do I install ruby 1.8 back while still keeping Ubuntu 14.04 on my computer? Any PPA's to add? I tried compiling from source but got a bunch of errors.

Comment: It does support 14.04 and 15.04 Date 25th of October 2015 I needed it for Wine-Doors (old Wine-app, does only use ruby1.8)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did this by adding the saucy (13.10) repositories back to my `sources.list` file.

1. `sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`
2. Add `deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy main restricted` after the first set.
3. Save the file and exit the editor.
4. `sudo apt-get update`
5. `sudo apt-get install ruby1.8`
6. `sudo apt-get install rubygems`

Probably isn't the best way, but it seemed to work for me. I had an older project with compass/sass that was failing on ruby 1.9 but now works as before.

I noticed that installing ruby 1.8 also installed a package called `ruby-switch`. Might be able to switch between 1.8 and 1.9 with this utility, although I haven't played with it and RVM is probably a better solution for switching ruby versions.

Comment: Yes, this is what I finally came to.. more or less. Using different steps and tools but the basic idea is the same - using "saucy" repositories again.

Comment: Since 13.10 is end-of-life now, I'm wondering if it may soon be necessary to [use the corresponding old-releases software source](http://askubuntu.com/q/91815/22949) for that `deb` line. As a totally separate matter, note that some software from saucy (or any Ubuntu version) got [SRUs](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates) after 13.10's release; in that case one would use `saucy-updates` or `saucy-security` instead of `saucy`. As shown on [this cached page](https://web.archive.org/web/20130724063921/https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ruby1.8), `ruby1.8` did not so `saucy` is correct.

Answer (score 6):

You should not use repos that are for older versions. You will run into severe maintenance problems and possibly break your system.

Use a PPA [like this one](http://brightbox.com/docs/ruby/ubuntu/):

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:brightbox/ruby-ng
sudo apt-get update
```

**EDIT**: As pointed out in the comments, they don't support 14.04 just yet, but they have an [experimental repository](https://launchpad.net/~brightbox/+archive/ubuntu/ruby-ng-experimental) that has packages for Trusty.

Comment: Note that this doesn't work for 14.04.  "We provide Ruby 1.8.7 packages for Ubuntu Lucid, Precise, Quantal, Raring and Saucy."

Comment: @tubaguy50035 thanks, I've extended my answer.

Comment: The first command should be `sudo apt-get install software-properties-common`.